# What is the video format and embed method that supports almost all browsers in different platforms and in different devices

Tags: php, android, iphone, html, video

I am creating an **Online Learning Web System** where users can upload and share their video tutorials.

Users may Upload any video types such as (**MP4, FLV, F4V, WMV, OGV, 3GP**)
This Web system is having responsive UI using Bootstrap and available for

> [Browsers: **Firefox, IE9 ^, Chrome, Safari**]
>
> [Mobile: **Android, iPhone, Tabs and pads**]

***Question 1***

> I want a video format and the embed method (HTML5, JW Player) which enables all the users to view the video, in any device, without any issue like youtube (web + mobile).

***Question 2***

> Now lets say we have found a Video Format, How to handle if users upload multiple video formats, do i need to convert and store it in that single format?

Appreciate ur prompt reply,

Thank you.

Comment: As per my recommendation you should install FFmpeg at your server side convert all video to MP4 format. MP4 is good compressed format and almost browser and native Android/Iphone/Windows are support this format.So in future if you want to support for mobile application this will be reused without any modification.

Comment: @BirajZalavadia thank you for leading me to **FFmpeg**,
Need to do a research on this.

Answer (score 2):

1. The W3C has set HTML5 as the new web standard.  As such, most NEW web browsers will be able to play HTML5-compatible videos.  In my experience, these work almost universally, on a wide-range of applications and devices.  Just make sure to make the video scaleable.
2. Yes, you would need to do that in order to have all of them in the same format.  You can convert online in many instances, though.  YouTube, honestly, might not be a bad way to go - can your users upload to YouTube and then submit them?  Also, there are multiple tools online that can convert videos.

Comment: 1) What do u mean by "Video Scalable"?             2) The users will not even know what format they are uploading, it's the developers task to do all back-end conversion stuff, in order to maintain the user friendliness. (uploading to youtube, not a good idea)

Comment: @ShareekAhamed, it seems like you know more about this than me, so I apologize if I've said anything incorrect, but I'll try to explain my rationale.  By "scaleable video," I mean something that does not stay the same size.  If you're expecting the user to provide the video, dimensions either need to be restricted, or you'll need to resize (scale) them.  In many cases, I've had to shrink videos drastically, and if the HTML5 is set to unscaleable (I work mostly with Contribute vids), it's a disaster.  Why isn't YouTube a good idea?  Major companies use it all of the time.